# Assembly 8086 about dw instruction

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm working with 8086 proccessor, Is it possible to change the value of a word I first declared on the top?
**Like this**

```
;_____Variables_____;
X dw 0
;_____code_____;
(...)
mov ax, 65535
mov X, ax
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, certainly.  Didn't you try it?  (Note some assemblers have you write `mov [X], ax` instead.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'm using Visual Studio Code as my IDE. 
I wondered where the words were written when declared, if RAM or ROM. That's the origin of my question. How do I reccomend u or something? lol

Comment: The `.code` section is usually read-only under a modern OS, but 8086 doesn't have memory protection.  (And emu8086 emulates a DOS system that loads programs into RAM.  Not developing firmware to go into the ROM of an IBM-PC.  That's why you can use `int 10h` BIOS interrupts and so on, because there already is a BIOS in ROM.)

Comment: `dw` is an assembler directive, not an instruction

Comment: @phuclv: you can look at as a pseudo-instruction.  Syntactically, it works like an instruction, taking operands (although a list instead of a fixed set).  And in terms of how it assembles, it's like having no opcode, only immediate bytes.  In fact, [NASM docs](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2) even call it a pseudo-instruction.    Still, calling it an "instruction" is probably a sign of some kind of misunderstanding (e.g. it doesn't actually *run*, unless you put it where execution would reach it), so fair enough.